# How to manually install zenity in homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, wine

**Zenity** is required for some apps like **winetrick-gtk** and its not installed automatically when you install **winetricks**. The problem is **brew install zenity** does not work, as such a package does not exist. The question is how can I install it manually in **Homebrew**?

I have installed **zenity** using **Macports**. However, every time I use **Homebrew** I get a warning complaining that **Macports** is installed. So if I can install it using **Homebrew** I will be able to get rid of **Macports** as I don't use it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [homebrew-x11 tap](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-x11) provides a formula for zenity, so just `brew install homebrew/x11/zenity`.

Comment: From the homebrew-x11 tap page on GitHub: it looks like homebrew-x11 formulae "were migrated to homebrew-core or deleted" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472547/1283667).

Answer (score 15):

For anyone arriving now, the x11 tap has been merged upstream, so you can simply `brew install zenity` and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a (largely compatible) *"port"* that doesn't require X:

```
brew install ncruces/tap/zenity
```

Source code: https://github.com/ncruces/zenity